# Sqoop Import: Sqoop show import success, but HDFS don't have data

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

When I try:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb --username root --password 123 --table equipment
```

It show:

```
INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 2.4714 seconds(0 bytes/sec)

INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 2 records.
```

[image: Sqoop import]

I think "Transferred 0 bytes in 2.4714 seconds(0 bytes/sec)" is not true. So I try: `hadoop fs -ls`. It show:

```
drwxr-xr-x  -  hduser supergroup  0  2017-02-11 00:34 equipment  -> (don't have data)

-rw-r--r--  1  hduser supergroup 140 2017-02-10 15:26 input1.txt (have data)
```

[image: Show data in hdfs]

Can you help me?

Comment: do you have any records in your mysql table `equipment` as its saying **`Transferred 0 bytes`**

Comment: Is the same sqoop command you are using? Coz, i dont see any target-dir mentioned... check your sqoop command.

Comment: @PrasadKhode I have 5 records in table equipment

Comment: @SathiyanS When I try: "sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb --username root --password 123 --table equipment --target-dir /usr/luanvan/equipment"
 it shown: "Transferred 0 bytes in 2.4714 seconds(0 bytes/sec)".
But I try: "ls /usr/luanvan/equipment" it have data

Comment: @Ken, when no `--target-dir` is passed to sqoop import, the data is imported into `/user/sqoop/tablename/` by default. Can you look into that directory for data?